# Python Dataframe Checking for a value then adding values to another DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe with a column with either a 1 or 0 in it.
This is the Signal column.
I want to cycle through this dataframe until I get to the first 1 then take the value in the Open column and put that into another Dataframe Total, column Buy
Then as it continues through the dataframe when it reaches the first 0 then take that value in the Open column and put that into the same Dataframe Total, column Sold.

I know I need a loop within a loop but I'm not getting very far!

Any pointers/help would be appreciated!

```
Total = DataFrame()

for i in range(len(df)) :

  if i.Signal == 1 :
    Total['Buy'] = i.Open
      if i.Signal == 0:
        Total['Sold'] = i.Open
```

I know the code is wrong!

Cheers

[Example of DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZWT3.png)

Comment: Maybe it would help if you show an example of `df` and the expected `Total`. e.g. if in `df.Signal` we have 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, what do you expect `Total.Sold` to have in the first row? The value of the fourth row or the value of the first row of `df.Open`? What about the second 1 (third row) of `df`? Should it be added to `Total` or should it be skipped?

Comment: Hi

Sorry!

The original dataframe has rows which contains OPEN and SIGNAL.
The new dataframe needs to have a row which contains the OPEN amount from the two rows of the original dataframe where the first ROW had a 1 in the SIGNAL column and the second ROW had a 0 in the SIGNAL column. I want to be be able to then work out the difference between the 0 OPEN amount and 1 OPEN amount.

Hope that clears things up? :-)

Comment: I have just added an image of the ORIGINAL DATAFRAME which might help. There are hundreds of rows. But I need the START and END of the trade to work out whether it made any profit or not! I am currently doing this manually which is taking ages which is why I wanted to try and automate it! Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: This is the link to the image!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZWT3.png

Comment: The first row in the dataframe TOTAL should have 0.5197 in BUY and 0.5252 in SOLD. The second row in the TOTAL dataframe would be 0.5263 in BUY and then 0.5241 in SOLD and so on throughout the original dataframe... :-) All the values between the first 1 and then the first 0 after that we would ignore... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Signal': [0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0], 'Open': np.random.rand(20)})

>>> df

|    |   Signal |      Open |
|---:|---------:|----------:|
|  0 |        0 | 0.959061  |
|  1 |        0 | 0.820516  |
|  2 |        1 | 0.0562783 |
|  3 |        1 | 0.612508  |
|  4 |        1 | 0.288703  |
|  5 |        1 | 0.332118  |
|  6 |        0 | 0.949236  |
|  7 |        0 | 0.20909   |
|  8 |        1 | 0.574924  |
|  9 |        1 | 0.170012  |
| 10 |        1 | 0.0255655 |
| 11 |        1 | 0.788829  |
| 12 |        0 | 0.39462   |
| 13 |        0 | 0.493338  |
| 14 |        0 | 0.347471  |
| 15 |        1 | 0.574096  |
| 16 |        1 | 0.286367  |
| 17 |        1 | 0.131327  |
| 18 |        0 | 0.38943   |
| 19 |        0 | 0.592241  |
```

```
# get the position of the first 1
first_1 = (df['Signal']==1).idxmax()

# Create a mask with True in the position of the first 1
# and every time a different value appears (0 after a 1, or 1 after a 0)
mask = np.full(len(df), False)
mask[first_1] = True
for i in range (first_1 + 1, len(df)):
    mask[i] = df['Signal'][i] != df['Signal'][i-1]

>>> df[mask]

|    |   Signal |      Open |
|---:|---------:|----------:|
|  2 |        1 | 0.0562783 |
|  6 |        0 | 0.949236  |
|  8 |        1 | 0.574924  |
| 12 |        0 | 0.39462   |
| 15 |        1 | 0.574096  |
| 18 |        0 | 0.38943   |
```

```
# Create new DF with 'Buy' = odd values of masked df['Open']
# and 'Sold' = even values of masked df['Open']

open_values = df[mask]['Open'].to_numpy()
total = pd.DataFrame({'Buy': [open_values[i] for i in range(0, len(open_values), 2)], 'Sold': [open_values[i] for i in range(1, len(open_values), 2)]})

>>> total

|    |       Buy |     Sold |
|---:|----------:|---------:|
|  0 | 0.0562783 | 0.949236 |
|  1 | 0.574924  | 0.39462  |
|  2 | 0.574096  | 0.38943  |
```

It works under the assumption that the original `df` table ends with 0s and not with 1s, i.e. for each first 1 in a row, there must be at least one 0 afterwards.

The assumption makes sense since the objective is to take differences later.

If the last value is 1, it will produce `ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length`.

Comment: Thanks for that! :-)

I get the following error when I use the firs bit of your code...?

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: My mistake! the index was Time so I reset it so it ended up with numbers... :-)

Comment: Thanks so much Ignatius... It has helped massively! Learnt some stuff as well!! :-)